# How do I find the shortest common substring from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming a Python list:

```
['ayiy', 'ayiya', 'ayiyas', 'back', 'backu', 'backup', 'backup-', 'backup1', 'backuph', 'backupm', 'backups', 'bakc', 'bakcu', 'bakcup', 'bakcup-', 'best', 'best-', 'best-b', 'best-ba', 'best-n', 'best-na', 'bili', 'biliy', 'biliyi', 'biliyil', 'bith', 'bithu', 'bithun', 'bithunt', 'blac', 'black', 'blackh', 'blackho', 'boos', 'boost', 'boost-', 'boost-s', 'boost-y', 'bout', 'bouth', 'bouths', 'bugs', 'bugsb', 'bugsbu', 'bugsbun']
```

What is the best way to produce a set of unique substrings? (of minimum 3 characters, but more characters if they are not the shortest similar substring):

```
['ayi', 'bac', 'bak', 'bes', 'bil', 'bit', 'blac', 'boo', 'bou', 'bug']
```

Comment: What is your definition of "best"?

Comment: I don't understand the logic you are trying to implement. Why is `yiy` not in the result? It is also a 3-character substring.

Comment: `yiy` repeats the char `y`  @mkrieger1

Comment: Can you explain why you get 'blac' instead of 'bla' in your expected result.  If not for that, you would only need to do `{s[:3] for s in L}`

Comment: And why is `iya` not in the result?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not explaining myself well.  From a list or set containing: 'black', 'blake', 'blame', 'cheat', cheap'; I am looking to extract the the common substrings from two or more strings in the list, starting at index 0.  So this would be 'bla', 'chea'.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get to the full list of 3 letter substrings.

```
your_list = ['ayiy', 'ayiya', 'ayiyas', 'back', 'backu', 'backup', 'backup-', 'backup1', 'backuph', 'backupm', 'backups', 'bakc', 'bakcu', 'bakcup', 'bakcup-', 'best', 'best-', 'best-b', 'best-ba', 'best-n', 'best-na', 'bili', 'biliy', 'biliyi', 'biliyil', 'bith', 'bithu', 'bithun', 'bithunt', 'blac', 'black', 'blackh', 'blackho', 'boos', 'boost', 'boost-', 'boost-s', 'boost-y', 'bout', 'bouth', 'bouths', 'bugs', 'bugsb', 'bugsbu', 'bugsbun']

smallest_list = [x[:3] for x in your_list]

unique_list = [x for x in set(smallest_list) if smallest_list.count(x) > 1]

unique_list.sort()

print (unique_list)
```

The output will be:

```
['ayi', 'bac', 'bak', 'bes', 'bil', 'bit', 'bla', 'boo', 'bou', 'bug']
```

Note: This answer will only give the results you posted. If you are looking for all unique 3 char substrings from the original list, there are many more. For ex: `yiy`, `iya`, `ack`, `kup` and many more are part of the 3 letter substring that can meet the condition. If you want a solution for that, then the answer will be different.

To get the full 3 char list (where the 3 char string appears more than once), use this code:

```
full_3char_list = [xa[i:i+3] for xa in your_list for i in range(len(xa)-2)]

unique_3char_list = [x for x in set(full_3char_list) if full_3char_list.count(x) > 1]

unique_3char_list.sort()

print (unique_3char_list)
```

The output will be:

```
['ack', 'akc', 'ayi', 'bac', 'bak', 'bes', 'bil', 'bit', 'bla', 'boo', 'bou', 'bug', 'ckh', 'cku', 'cup', 'est', 'gsb', 'hun', 'ili', 'ith', 'iya', 'iyi', 'kcu', 'kup', 'lac', 'liy', 'oos', 'ost', 'out', 'sbu', 'st-', 't-b', 't-n', 'thu', 'ugs', 'up-', 'uth', 'yiy']
```

If you want the unique list of all 3 char strings, then you can just do a set on full_3char_list.

```
unique_3char_full_list = sorted(list(set(full_3char_list)))
print (unique_3char_full_list)

['-ba', '-na', 'ack', 'akc', 'ayi', 'bac', 'bak', 'bes', 'bil', 'bit', 'bla', 'boo', 'bou', 'bug', 'bun', 'ckh', 'cku', 'cup', 'est', 'gsb', 'hun', 'ili', 'ith', 'iya', 'iyi', 'kcu', 'kho', 'kup', 'lac', 'liy', 'oos', 'ost', 'out', 'sbu', 'st-', 't-b', 't-n', 't-s', 't-y', 'ths', 'thu', 'ugs', 'unt', 'up-', 'up1', 'uph', 'upm', 'ups', 'uth', 'yas', 'yil', 'yiy']
```